# how to get the next page link in scrapy

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, web-crawler

how to get the link "/zufang/dongcheng/pg2/" in "下一页"？

```
<a href="/zufang/dongcheng/pg2/" data-page="2">下一页</a>
```

I have tried this, but got nothing.

the url is "http://bj.lianjia.com/zufang/dongcheng/"

```
start_urls = (
            'http://bj.lianjia.com/zufang/dongcheng/',
    )

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[5]',)), callback="parse", follow= True),)


def parse(self, response):
            l = ItemLoader(item = ItjuziItem(),response=response)
            for i in range(0,len(response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']/h2/a/text()").extract())):
                    info = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']/h2/a/text()").extract()[i].encode('utf-8')
                    local = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']").xpath(".//span[@class='region']/text()").extract()[i].encode('utf-8') 
                    house_layout = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']").xpath(".//span[@class='zone']//text()").extract()[i].encode('utf-8')
                    house_square = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']").xpath(".//span[@class='meters']/text()").extract()[i].encode('utf-8')
                    house_orientation = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']").xpath(".//div[@class='where']//span/text()").extract()[(i + 1) * 4 - 1].encode('utf-8')
                    district = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']").xpath(".//div[@class='con']/a/text()").extract()[i].encode('utf-8')[:-6]
                    floor = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']").xpath(".//div[@class='con']//text()").extract()[(i + 1) * 5 - 3].encode('utf-8')
                    building_year = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']").xpath(".//div[@class='con']//text()").extract()[(i + 1) * 5 - 1].encode('utf-8')
                    price_month = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']").xpath(".//span[@class='num']//text()").extract()[(i + 1) * 2 - 2].encode('utf-8')
                    person_views = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-panel']").xpath(".//span[@class='num']//text()").extract()[(i + 1) * 2 - 1].encode('utf-8')
                    tags = []
                    for j in range(0,len(response.xpath("//div[@class='view-label left']")[i].xpath(".//span//text()").extract())):
                            tags.append(response.xpath("//div[@class='view-label left']")[i].xpath(".//span//text()").extract()[j].encode("utf-8"))
                    l.add_value('info',info)
                    l.add_value('local',local)
                    l.add_value('house_layout',house_layout)
                    l.add_value('house_square',house_square)
                    l.add_value('house_orientation',house_orientation)
                    l.add_value('district',district)
                    l.add_value('floor',floor)
                    l.add_value('building_year',building_year)
                    l.add_value('price_month',price_month)
                    l.add_value('person_views',person_views)
                    l.add_value('tags',tags)
                    print l
                    return l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the link and attach it to the current url

```
from urlparse import urljoin
yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.url,response.xpath("//a[@data-page]/@href").extract_first()), callback=self.parse)
```

or increment the page

```
for i in range(2,20):
    yield scrapy.Request("http://bj.lianjia.com/zufang/dongcheng/pg"+ str(i), callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: "response.xpath("//a[@data-page]/@href").extract_first()" returns "[]" .

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: perhaps you haven't seen the original page.I want to crawl most of the pages , but the range is not one stable number.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just keep appending the incremented value of the page no in the url.
Applicable to this link.

```
url = 'http://bj.lianjia.com/zufang/dongcheng/'

counter = 1
while <http error is null>:
    url_to_crawl = url + "/pg" + counter
    counter = counter + 1
    <crawl the url>
```

Comment: you can have a test ,even the long long no doesn't return error.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? Do you want to crawl all links on the page? Or do you want to collect data from this particular page?

Comment: almost all the data from these particular pages